# How to reverse while in php

Tags: php, html

i have this table which simply minus sold mobiles from recv mobile than show in balance mobiles and also plus old row balance whith new row.

```
|Received Mobiles |Mobile i have sold | Balance |
|6                |1                  |  5 
|3                |2                  |  6
|4                |2                  |  8 ----------> total mobiles i have
```

but i want to reverse (calculation start from the end) this result and want to show like that because i want to see new records at top

```
|Received Mobiles |Mobile i have sold | Balance |
|6                |1                  |  8 ----------> total mobiles i have
|3                |2                  |  3
|4                |2                  |  2 <------- plus with recv mob 3 then - sold mob
```

i am writing this

```
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

$recvtotal += $fetch[recv];
$soldtotal += $fetch[sold];

$balancing += $fetch[recv]-$fetch[sold];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $fetch[brand] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $fetch[recv] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $fetch[sold] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . ($balancing) . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";


}
```

Comment: I guess you forgot to ask the question here

Comment: you will need to compute your data once and then display it. so it needs 2 passes.

Comment: but i want to compute data from bottom

Comment: Maybe you should include your database query? I'd imagine you could use an `ORDER BY` clause to control how the results are returned.

Comment: if i sort order by id or date i inverse result but not calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add [**sorting**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) to your query? Just add an `ORDER BY` clause and you should be able invert  the order.

Comment: if i sort order by id or date i inverse result but not calculation